# Aligning 2 labels in column spanned table row

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I have a table with 6 columns, the bottom row spans all 6 columns and has a label in it aligned to the center. I need to add another label to this row and have it aligned to the left whilst maintaining the original label's center position.
When I add the new label and float it to the left the original label is moved to the right.
How can I align the new label to the left and still have the original label centered?

```
<table>
<tr>
<td style="border:solid; border-color:black; background-color:#e0e0eb;">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="false"></asp:Label>
</td>
<td style="border:solid; border-color:black; background-color:#e0e0eb;">
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="false"></asp:Label>
</td>
<td style="border:solid; border-color:black; background-color:#e0e0eb;">
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Font-Bold="false"></asp:Label>
</td>
<td style="border:solid; border-color:black; background-color:#e0e0eb;">
    <asp:Label ID="label4" runat="server" Font-Bold="false"></asp:Label>
</td>
<td style="border:solid; border-color:black; background-color:#e0e0eb;">
    <asp:Label ID="label5" runat="server" Font-Bold="false"></asp:Label>
</td>
<td style="border:solid; border-color:black; background-color:#e0e0eb;">
    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Font-Bold="false"></asp:Label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="6" style="border:solid; border-color:black; padding:10px; background-color:#99ccff;">
<asp:Label ID="NewLabel" runat="server" Font-Bold="false" Style="float:left;"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="OriginalLabel" runat="server" Font-Bold="false"></asp:Label>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: The original idea here was to introduce grid into the last row (6 column) cell. While this worked in isolation, when the cell was picking up its width from the rest of the table above it it did not.

This snippet therefore reverts to using a simpler layout - the left hand text is set as position absolute so it does not interfere with the centering calculations for the second text.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="border:solid; border-color:black; background-color:#e0e0eb;">
      Cell 1
    </td>
    <td style="border:solid; border-color:black; background-color:#e0e0eb;">
      Cell 2
    </td>
    <td style="border:solid; border-color:black; background-color:#e0e0eb;">
      Cell 3
    </td>
    <td style="border:solid; border-color:black; background-color:#e0e0eb;">
      Cell 4
    </td>
    <td style="border:solid; border-color:black; background-color:#e0e0eb;">
      Cell 5
    </td>
    <td style="border:solid; border-color:black; background-color:#e0e0eb;">
      Cell 6
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6" style="border:solid; border-color:black; padding:10px; background-color:#99ccff; position: relative;">
      <div style="position: absolute;">left label</div>
      <div style="text-align: center;">center label</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as it puts everything into column 1 and causes an issue with the row above I have added an example row above the row to the example.

Comment: You have to select the particular td that you want this on, not just have it on all of them.There wasnt enough in your original code in the question to know how to select. Perhaps with tr:las-child now?

Comment: Thanks for your time, I will have  play around with it.

Comment: You were quite right - the original snippet worked because it had a width set but when the width is picked up through the overall table then it did not work. A simpler way forward is suggested in the answer now.